# FreeBSD 9 (amd64) reboot/shutdown process is very slow

Tags: freebsd, raid10

I have a Dell Poweredge 2900 III with FreeBSD 9 (amd64), the server uses mfi wich handles a raid10, I had to reboot the server, but notice that either when rebooting or shutting down the server, something is going wrong, besides taking to much time to reboot/shutdown, after rebooting I notice that that some ldap instances within some jails could'nt start and this was because the database was corrupted.

This make me think that probably something was wrong with the disks or mfi card, but  checking the disk array / logs everything seems to be working fine.

My set up is something like this:

Host server has the minimum base of FreeBSD 9 amd64, within I create some jails, the ones contain services like mysql, email, and some others ldap.

With FreeBSD 7 and 8 I didn't notice this behavior but with FreeBSD 9 something is not working well. I did a clean installation of FreeBSD 9 and root filesystem is using ZFS.

Attached is an image hoping some one can give me a hint of what to check or any kind of advice.

[reboot capture screen image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/saz35)

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting and stopping your jails via /etc/rc.d/jail ? It looks like the server is not waiting for the jail process to finish.

So either they are not shut down correctly, or the problem is in the jail. Make sure the jails are stopped via an init script and that they shut down correctly.

Comment: Hi, yes, jails are all handled via the /etc/rc.d/jail, in some tests I also stopped all the jails manually and later executed the shutdown command, but same behavior occurred.  One think I notice is that when shutting down the server and all jails where stopped  is that the shutdown sequence started again the jails and later try to shutdown them.